# Retrieving LoggedIn User in Base Page Model Class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I use ASP.NET Core Identity for the user management activities along with EF Core for the database interaction. I have successfully implemented the login functionality using Identity. And I am able to get the logged in user object (as CliamsPrincipal object) in my razor page classes.

All my razor pages inherit a custom base class, and that base class inherit the default "PageModel" class. In my razor pages, I have the logic to written to save entities into the database. When saving those entities, the user who created the entity object is stored as well (db level, user ID is stored).

The user class is known as "ApplicationUser" which inherit the AspNet Core Identity "IdentityUser". ApplicationUser is stored in the database against the each save of my entities.

I can simply write this logic in each razor page model class, but it would be a duplication of the same code in each razor pages. Therefore I want to centralized the code in retrieving the logged in user as a "ApplicationUser" object in my base page model class. And expose the logged in user as property from that class.

However I am bit struggling to implement that in my base page model class and the code I have written seems not to be working. The "User" (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal) in PageModel.User object is null. even though user is successfully logged in.

In the debugging phase I found out that during the execution the razor page constructor the User object is null, but however the User object get assigned with logged in user in the OnGet page handler method (as an example).

Below is the code that I have implemented

```
public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser>        userManager;

    public ApplicationUser LoggedInUser  {  get; set;   }


    public BasePageModel() { }


    public BasePageModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) 
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        GetLoggedInUser();
    }        

    

    private async void GetLoggedInUser()
    {
        LoggedInUser =  await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    }
}
```

Page model class

```
[Authorize]
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel, IBasePageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel>                logger;

    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }


    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IOptions<ApplicationSetting> appSettings, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) : base(userManager)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        ApplicationName     = appSettings.Value.Name;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {  
      return Page();
    }
    
    public void OnPost()
    {
        //SaveMethod(PostObj, LoggedInUser);
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices method in Startup class

```
services.AddScoped<BasePageModel, BasePageModel>();
```

If there is a better way to centralize this logic or improve in retrieving the logged in user, I am all ears.